# Facebook geotargeting of a post has misspellings

Tags: facebook-graph-api, targeting

For Facebook post geotargeting, there is a file that contains the cities:
http://developers.facebook.com/attachment/all_cities_final.csv

There is also:
http://developers.facebook.com/attachment/targeting_ids.json
that contains the countries, cities and languages. (This one only has major cities listed, now all cities as the csv file above)

There are some misspellings of certain cities. For example:
"id":608757,"value":"Århus" is from the json (which is correct)
However, the CSV files DK,,rhus,608757 (the CSV doesn't have that first character correctly).

For other people that have done geotargeting, which file are you using?

I'm having a very hard time finding the Facebook documentation around this.

Trying to figure out the following:
What is recommended when finding this sort of issues: file this in Facebook?
Will they be updating these files at some point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend filing a bug when you find these kinds of issues.

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Thanks, I've filed in facebook http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/192649667495143

Comment: Update: I was trying to accomplish geotargeting in the old way, should have referred to here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/get-autocomplete-data/